# Заменить ссылки на утерянные файлы ссылками с другого ресурса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Перенёс сайт со старого хостинга и домена на новое. Однако при переносе не все картинки галерей перенеслись. Где-то утеряно полное изображение, где-то его превью.
Хочу решить задачу потерянных картинок следующим образом на JS или JQuery.
Удаляем со страницы галереи все ненайденные превьюшки, чтобы они не создавали отступы.
Заменяем ссылки на все ненайденные изображения ссылками со старого сайта простым измененнием домена в адресе ссылки

Ещё раз вопрос: то есть на старом сайте у нас галерея имеет вид:

```
<ul class="gallery">
<li>
<a href="http://olddomen.ru/images/32427.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium"> 
<img src="http://olddomen.ru/images/32427t.jpg">   
</a> 
</li>

<li>
<a href="http://olddomen.ru/images/32428.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium"> 
<img src="http://olddomen.ru/images/32428t.jpg">   
</a> 
</li>
</ul>
```

Картинка 32428 - основная, 32428t - её превью.

А на новом сайте у нас имеются повреждения:

```
<ul class="gallery">
<li><a href="http://newdomen.ru/images/32427.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium"> 
<img src="">
(не найдена превью картинки)       
</a> 
</li>
<li><a href="http://newdomen.ru/images/32428.jpg" title="" rel="lightbox-atomium"> 
(ответ консоли GET http://newdomen.ru/images/32428.jpg 404 (Not Found))
<img src="http://newdomen.ru/images/32428t.jpg"> 
              
</a> 
</ul>
```

Где не найдена превью, хочу избавиться вообще, то есть для родительского li сделать display:none,
а где ответ 404 - там надо заменить в адресе "newdomen", на "olddomen" - ведь все картинки есть на старом домене.

Comment: Теперь понимаю почему часто стали указывать такие ссылки `/images/bla-bla-bla.png`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая часть решения будет выглядить так

```
$('a:has(img[src=""])').each(function(){ 
        $(this).parent().hide();
```